# Kafka with .Net Client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to use kafka on our production environment. I want to know if the latest version of client is bug free for production launch. Is it working with consumer group? I want to pass 10000 records per second, is it suitable for it or not?

Comment: What client do you choose?

Answer (score 9):

Currently [microsoft kafka client](https://github.com/Microsoft/CSharpClient-for-Kafka) is not actively developed/supported. Instead the author recommends to use [rdkafka-dotnet](https://github.com/ah-/rdkafka-dotnet) It has better documentation and is easy to use

Comment: Now rdkafka-dotnet recommends confluent-kafka-dotnet https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

Answer (score 3):

We are using Kafka in production using DotNet client. Here is the most up-to update and official supported version https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

confluent-kafka-dotnet is derived from librdkafka (https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/)

Answer (score 2):

I am only aware of a single .net Kafka Client (https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net) and the README say clearly:

> The current version of this project is a functioning "work in progress" as it was only started in early February.

Furthermore:

> This is a pet project for me and is not currently backed by a need for a Kafka server client. Which means the client is only currently being tested against a small set of Kafka test servers and not against any server that has any real data load.

A list of available clients is maintained here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients
So you can watch if another .net client becomes available.